# Laravel jwt auth Token Signature could not be verified

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I am facing a very strange problem. If I enter this following url in my browser it returns the user correctly

`http://192.168.0.100:8000/app/getUser?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC8xOTIuMTY4LjAuMTAwOjgwMDBcL2FwcFwvbG9naW4iLCJpYXQiOjE1Nzk5NjAwMTcsImV4cCI6MjQyODU4ODAwMTcsIm5iZiI6MTU3OTk2MDAxNywianRpIjoiYlFiYXIyVEJIdVJNN1lUSCIsInN1YiI6MTcsInBydiI6Ijg3ZTBhZjFlZjlmZDE1ODEyZmRlYzk3MTUzYTE0ZTBiMDQ3NTQ2YWEifQ.KLsnS769zthfFWth5Z4BeWDP6K0zEQ5eTONpKdlJMbA`

But if I send a get request from postman or my app, it gives me error like this

```
[2020-01-25 13:49:43] local.ERROR: Token Signature could not be verified. {"userId":17,"exception":"[object] (Tymon\\JWTAuth\\Exceptions\\TokenInvalidException(code: 0): Token Signature could not be verified. at /Users/mdzainalabedin/laravel/olvboxapi/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Providers/JWT/Lcobucci.php:137)
[stacktrace]
#0 /Users/mdzainalabedin/laravel/olvboxapi/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Manager.php(101): Tymon\\JWTAuth\\Providers\\JWT\\Lcobucci->decode('eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q...')
#1 /Users/mdzainalabedin/laravel/olvboxapi/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/JWT.php(200): Tymon\\JWTAuth\\Manager->decode(Object(Tymon\\JWTAuth\\Token))
```

My function is this

```
public function getUserInfo(Request $request){
   \Log::info($request);
   return $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
}
```

Both has valid same token but still gives different result. Any idea what could be wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's the same url I am hitting with ?token='here is the same token I added' this way get works in browser but not in postpman. also both token are same when log them.

Answer (score 2):

your question is unclear about how you pass the token using postman 
but i guess using the below method to passing the token would solve the problem:

```
Bearer
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC8xOTIuMTY4LjAuMTAwOjgwMDBcL2FwcFwvbG9naW4iLCJpYXQiOjE1Nzk5NjAwMTcsImV4cCI6MjQyODU4ODAwMTcsIm5iZiI6MTU3OTk2MDAxNywianRpIjoiYlFiYXIyVEJIdVJNN1lUSCIsInN1YiI6MTcsInBydiI6Ijg3ZTBhZjFlZjlmZDE1ODEyZmRlYzk3MTUzYTE0ZTBiMDQ3NTQ2YWEifQ.KLsnS769zthfFWth5Z4BeWDP6K0zEQ5eTONpKdlJMbA
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems works. I have been passing token in the request url for so long and it works. Now need to pass it as bearer header. Thank you